# Printing multiple Bash command output in jupyter notebook not show results

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Having a simple file executing in python a list of commands like:

```
import subprocess

def run_bash_commands(commands):
    for command in commands:
        try:
            output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
            print(output.decode('utf-8'))  # Print the output
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(f"Error executing {command}: {e}")

# Example list of commands
bash_commands = [
    'echo Hello',
    'ls -l',
]

run_bash_commands(bash_commands)
```

when I do `import utils.py` in the notebook located in the same dir as the `utils.py` the script does not print enything.

**How to print result of `run_bash_commands` in jupyter notebook?**

**EDIT**

I noticed that when I restart notebook kernel, then for the first cell execution, the notebook will show the output of the function, but after second execution of cel with `import utils` it starts to return nothing. To see result it only show it for the first execution after kernel restart.

**How to make it show output after every execution of the `import utils` cell?**

Comment: I think you are mistaken on how imports work, even if you separate it from Jupyter. I think. You honestly aren't showing us everything going on here. I assume the only code block you are sharing is `utils.py`. What exactly are you running in your notebook? Now that what you don't say is out of the way, you seem to be mistaken on how `import` works. If you did this in the Python console/interpreter you'd have the same issue. When Python first imports code, it imports that in the namespace. In the same session if it has already imported the code, it does nothing unless you do something special.

Comment: <continued> And so that is the behavior you are seeing. It isn't related to Jupyter. You should be constructing your code and calls differently based on a better understanding of importing now. Usually you put the functions in the import and then invoke the function in the calls. Take all this with a grain of salt; like I said, it's hard to tell what you are doing because you only provide one code block and only leave me to presume that is `utils.py` after-the-fact, & aren't sharing the notebook part. I should add that it instead of import **you may want to do`%run utils.py` in the notebook**.

Comment: <continued> Read about the magic `%run` command Jupyter inherits from IPython [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). It is like running `python utils.py` inside your notebook but it has WAY more features than that. One of them is the ability to use it interactively. In fact, **you may want to be running `%run -i utils.py` in your notebook**. Read about the 'interactive' flag under 'Options' there in the documentation of the magic command. Keep in mind I'm still not sure what you are trying to specifically accomplish. You may still want `import`.

Comment: @Wayne Apologies for not sharing enough context. Your assumptions are wright. My utils is a collection of diagnostic shell commands such as `nvidia-smi`, `nvcc -version` 'du -h' that I wanted easily to be run from a single cell of jupyter notebook in a oneliner. Your answer with `%run utils.py` actually make it possible. Tahnks you for your help and please make it as post, so that I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that instead of import you may want to do `%run utils.py` in the notebook.
You can read about the magic %run command Jupyter inherits from IPython [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). It is like running `python utils.py` inside your notebook, but it has WAY more features than that.
One of the extra features is the ability to use it interactively, using the 'interactive' (`-i`) flag under 'Options' [there in the documentation of the magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). It allows you to use the script in the namespace of the notebook and so when developing you can set a variable in the notebook and then when the script is run it can use the state of the variable in the script that gets executed in the same namespace as the notebook.

---

Imports in Python work that it imports the code once into the namespace. And then in the same session if it encounters the same import again, it doesn't import it. That is why you have to do something special to reload imports when developing.